# ActionCable send message on page load

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable

I want to send message to ActionCable server on a page load... But ActionCable not connected at that time.
How to delay message sending until ActionCable will connect to server?

Answer (score 0):

Defining callback for turbolinks:load inside connected: function will give you what you want

Comment: I guess i'm not described my problem correctly. I have turbolinks, so actioncable connects once per opened page, but multiple pages loads through turbolinks.
I guess defining callback for `turbolinks:load` inside connected: function will give me what i want. Please change your answer so i can accept it.